# Using leaflet-image while hiding the leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Is there any way to draw and render a leaflet map into an image without displaying it ?

I'm currently using leaflet-image and each time I need to render and the only way I have found to work is to append the canvas before rendering and removing it after. But it make the map visible for a few seconds and I don't want that.

I also randomly get this error sometimes :

```
Element could not be drawn on canvas 
<canvas class="leaflet-zoom-animated" style="transform: translate3d(0…idth: 0px; height: 0px;" width="0" height="0">
```

Here's my current code :

```
import L from 'leaflet';
import leafletImage from 'leaflet-image';


var map = null;
var hiddenMap = document.createElement('div');

function getMap(){
  document.body.appendChild(hiddenMap);

  if(map)
    return map;

  hiddenMap.setAttribute('style', 'width: 790px; height: 250px;');

  map = L.map(hiddenMap, { renderer: L.canvas() });
  L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
    id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1,
    accessToken: process.env.VUE_APP_MAP_BOX_TOKEN
  }).addTo(map);
  map.invalidateSize();
  return map;
}

function cleanMap(){
  document.body.removeChild(hiddenMap);
}


export function render(lats, longs){
  if(lats.length == 0 || longs.length == 0)
    return null;

  var m;

  try{
    m = getMap();

    var coords = new Array(lats.length);
    for(var i=0; i<lats.length; i++){
      coords[i] = new L.LatLng(lats[i], longs[i]);
    }
    m.fitBounds(coords);

    var path = new L.Polyline(coords, {
      color: 'red',
      weight: 3,
      opacity: 0.5,
      smoothFactor: 1
    }).addTo(m);

  }catch(err){
    console.error(err);
    return null;
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    leafletImage(m, function(err, canvas) {
      path.remove(m);
      cleanMap();
      if(err)
        reject(err);
      resolve(canvas.toDataURL().replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, ""));
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I suspect there's a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here, and there might be a simpler way of creating the images from the source data. So, what's the use case?

Comment: Basically the user of my app can upload a route he just took. I need the image of the map with the path to store it on the server to display it to other user (other user will be able to see the map with more details in a leaflet canvas if they want too, but it's a lot cheaper to just display a generated image as a summary first since 90% of the time they will just scroll through the list of routes).

Comment: I will argue that's it's simpler to render the route thumbnail on the server (since the server has the full route). Rendering stuff in the browser is one more (undesirable) point of failure.

Comment: afaik leaflet isn't really usable server side ? I tried looking for other library that could support rendering of map with some graphics on top server side but haven't found any.